# Small piece of CSS won't work in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm completely new to the entire process of building a site (this is my first one). I'm using filezilla to upload my files. Anyway, I made some modifications to my css and then updated the file. It shows properly in Firefox, but for some reason Chrome won't display the changes. I've never had this problem before with Chrome, and when I view the file itself on the browser, it is showing properly. I checked my code but can't find anything wrong with it. Here's the problematic CSS but I don't know if that will help at all. Thank you in advance!

```
.neighborhood-guides {
background-color: #DEDCDA;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-top: 20px;
}

.neighborhood-guides h2 {
color: #393c3d;
font-size: 28px;
font-family: 'Vollkorn', sans-serif;
}

.neighborhood-guides p {
font-size: 22px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
font-family: 'Vollkorn', sans-serif;
}

.neighborhood-guides ul {
color: #393c3d;
font-size: 22px;
list-style: none;
font-family: 'Vollkorn', sans-serif;
margin-left: 0px;
padding-left: 5px;
}

.neighborhood-guides a {
font-family: 'Vollkorn', sans-serif;
font-size: 27px;
margin-left: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#hourz {
font-family: 'Vollkorn', sans-serif;
display: inline-block;

}

#hourz li {
font-size: 16px;
}

#meoww {
margin-left: 40px;
font-size: 25px;
}

.featured {
height:70px;
background-color:#FF8585;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
font-family: 'Vollkorn', sans-serif;
}

.featured p {
font-size: 40px;
color: #fff;
margin-left: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: What bit is not working in Chrome but is in FireFox? Have you tried a hard reload in chrome? (With developer tools open right click the refresh icon and choose hard reload)

Comment: Maybe you have caching problems? Try hit F12 or (CTRL+SHIFT+I) and then choose "Network tab"(second from left) --> then press the checkbox that says "disable cache". Press F5.

Comment: I think you guys were right. Actually when I checked the page the next day the changes finally showed up. Now I'll know what to do if I run into this again.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely a caching problem, if you make your HTML into a php file you can add this to the CSS link in the php, follow the example below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" />
```

This essentially puts a timestamp on your CSS code, the browser will always refresh to the newest available version since the time changed.

Here is the part you want specifically:

```
?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" />
```

Dont forget that you must change your **index.html** to **index.php**, you will still be able to edit your index.php file but will not be able to see it locally, in order to do that upload it to your server if you have one or see more about [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

This will definitely be worth it in the long run as not everyone has their cache disabled.

**EDIT**
This will also work for others who might visit your page that have a earlier out of date version of your CSS cached away.

Comment: Thank you! The page was working properly about 12 hours after I posted this, but I think I'll try to implement this so that I don't run into this problem in the future.

Comment: Right that signifies a problem in caching. Basically your website has a cache refresh time which means the browser will update the cache to your site every 12 - 24 hours depending on the site. This is to keep the load times of your site to a minimum. However, if you minify your CSS then this will not be a problem :) Glad I could help for sure!